# Variable number of updates to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP page that is interacting with a MYSQL database using PDO. I have a function that updates numerous fields in the database as requested. Since I do not know how many fields will be updated in advance, it is tricky to write a single query. Which of these methods is preferable (or is there another better way I do not know about)?

**Query Building**

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET ";
foreach ($changes as $field => $new_value)
{
    $valid_field = validate_field($field);
    $query .= "${valid_field} = :${valid_field} ";
}
$query = "WHERE id = :id ;";
// Prepare statement, bind values, execute, check for errors, etc
```

From what I have heard, this is not preferable. I tend to agree; this looks kinda ugly.

**Transaction**

```
$pdo_object->beginTransaction();
foreach ($changes as $field => $new_value)
{
    $valid_field = validate_field($field);
    $query = "UPDATE users SET ${valid_field} = :${valid_field} WHERE id = :id";
    // Prepare statement, bind values, execute, check for errors, etc
}
$pdo_object->commit();
```

This seems safer to me, but the way it is written it looks like it searches the table for the row with that ID many times rather than just once like the other query.

Is the Query Building method faster than the Transaction method? Should the Transaction method be used despite slower speed for safety/security reasons?

Comment: The query building method is faster since you are executing overall less queries. But unless your table has hundreds of columns in it or you are updating hundreds of rows, you probably won't notice much of a difference if you did decide to update one field at a time. Personally I tend to try to minimize the number of queries as much as possible, even if it leads to code that is *slightly* harder to follow. Just document it well and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, transactions *(which, in MySQL, requires use of "InnoDB" tables ...)* are quite efficient.  The database engine will *(probably ...)* lock all of the storage pages that are covered by the query, and might delay actually writing the pages back to the store until after the transaction `COMMIT`s.

My suggestion is simply:  *(a)* don't be afraid of transactions when they seem to be called for, and *(b)*, "just focus on simplicity and clarity."  Write code that is obvious, easy to read, and easy to maintain.  Then, presume that the SQL engine knows how to do *its* job.  :-)

Comment: Hey, we have the same name. My last name is Robinson too.

Comment: Very common.  I used to keep a collection of cases when "our name" made the papers.  (When someone with "our name" *died* in a local community, my parents got more-than a few "guarded calls.")  But my real problem is that I "look like" lots of people.  I'm afraid that when I walk into a Post Office, someone might say ... *"there he is!"*

Comment: *"Bwahahahaha!!* It **is** 'he!'  *You'll never catch me alive!!"*  ;-)